# Check if file has already been moved?

Tags: powershell, file

So right now I have a program that moves files automatically from one folder to another **only once**.
So if that file gets into that folder again, it shouldn't be moved.The application is being executed every 30 minutes. So right now what I have is if LastWriteTime is older than 30 minutes, don't move it.

```
# Check if file is older than 30 minutes
$olderthan = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $src\$_.pdf | ? { $_.LastWriteTime -ge $date} -ov olderthan)
 
if (-not $olderthan){      
 
    # If it's older than 30 minutes, move no file
    $timesall = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $src\$_.pdf | Select-Object -Property BaseName)
    write-LogRecord -Typ WARNING "'$($timesall.BaseName)' file(s) are not being moved because they're older than 30 minutes"   
    $timesall = 0 
 
} else {

 #Move File

}
```

And yes it works, but are there other, better ways to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you describe the folders or give an example file tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other alternative to inspecting file attributes is to do file tracking.  I'll assume that the files do not continue to live in the destination folder (otherwise you can use `TEST-PATH` to see if a file exists before moving).

To me, the most straight forward tracking system would be to create a parallel folder where you can put files with the same name into it. Assuming the file has not been submitted before you would copy A.txt into your destination, and create a A.txt in your tracking path (which could be a empty file, or not, see below).  Now you test is to see if the same named file exists in your tracking folder.

*Note: this method allows you to easily reprocess a file by removing it from your tracking folder.  It also just works when the scheduler does not fire, for whatever reason.*

If you need more complex options, like accommodating a file that has changed, you could store finger print information, like size and a hash, in your tracking file.  Your test the could also inspect those as part of it's test.

Lastly, at some point you'd probably want to groom your tracking folder.  Using LastWriteTime and removing everything past, say, 1 month (or whatever if right for your circumstances) would keep your tracking folder from getting too big.  You could run this every time after the transfers, or on a separate schedule.